# Font that is monospaced + slash through zeros + "web safe"

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation, glyphs, web-safe

When ever character matters (code development, etc.), there is a need for a font that meets the following:

1. Monospaced
2. Easily distinguishes between the uppercase letter O and the number 0. (Two circles with slightly different widths leaves plenty of room for error.)
3. Easily distinguishes between the number 1, lowercase L and uppercase L
4. Included on most devices ("Web safe"?)

Different characters that appear identical are known as "homoglyphs".

Example *image* of "Segoe UI" font failing the first three requirements (most importantly #2 and #3):
[image: Segoe UI capital O and number 0]
[image: Segoe UI number 1, lowercase l, and uppercase L]

Example *image* of "Consolas" font passing first three requirements:
[image: Consolas capital O and number 0]
[image: Consolas number 1, lowercase l, and uppercase L]

For fun, here are the same characters as *text*, presented with the "code sample" formatting. How they are displayed is dependent on your device:

```
O 0    1 l L
```

Finding a font that passes requirement 1 through 3 isn't hard to find - Consolas is a good choice. But as I'm aware, Consolas isn't included by default on most if not all Mac OS. So what are some next-best choices?

Comment: Works fine here, macOS Mojave. Font appears to be Menlo - https://i.stack.imgur.com/MslPD.png Stack Exchange just [switched to using system fonts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364048/we-are-switching-to-system-fonts-on-may-10-2021), so I'd guess that's the default. I have neither Segoe nor Consolas, so I can't compare.

Comment: [I'm not much of a font 'eggspurt' so I'm not sure whether I ought to post that as an answer or not]

Comment: @Tetsujin My Windows 10 machine doesn't have Menlo. :( Good to know of it for Macs though.

Comment: Unless you have some very specific requirements, ‘web safe’ isn’t really a thing anymore. Web fonts are almost universally supported now, and using something from Google Fonts will give you excellent results nearly everywhere.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Whatever the correct term may be, I'm looking for a monospaced font that avoids common homoglyphs. What's a font that meets that requirement and can be obtained from Google Fonts? Does Consolas fit that bill?

Comment: @Bort There are quite a lot. Go to Google Fonts, click on _Categories_ and deselect everything except _Monospace_, then in the “Type something” field type in “0 O 1 l I” (or whatever you want to test), and you’ll get a list of about 25 fonts. You can then easily see which ones distinguish the characters clearly enough and choose based on that.

Answer (score 1):

See @Janus Bahs Jacuuet's comment on the original question. I just ended up using a Google Font: https://fonts.google.com/

I went with 'Source Code Pro', but there are many monospace fonts that meet the original poster's requirements.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Styling_text/Web_fonts :

- Go to Google Fonts.
- Use the filters on the left-hand side to display the kinds of fonts you want to choose and choose a couple of fonts you like.
- To select a font family, press the `⊕` button alongside it.
- When you've chosen the font families, press the [Number] Families Selected bar at the bottom of the page.
- In the resulting screen, you first need to copy the line of HTML code shown and paste it into the head of your HTML file. Put it above the existing `<link>` element, so that the font is imported before you try to use it in your CSS.
- You then need to copy the CSS declarations listed into your CSS as appropriate, to apply the custom fonts to your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If your budget allows licensing a font, I really recommend [fonts by Toshi Omagari](https://www.myfonts.com/foundry/tabular-type-foundry/), a font designer who specialises in monospace fonts. (Full disclosure: I've met him, he's a really nice guy.) Many of his fonts e.g. [Codelia](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/tabular-type-foundry/codelia/) or [Belinsky Text](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/tabular-type-foundry/belinsky-text/) fit your requirements and have a lot of character.